# Layout relative anchor in a RelativeLayout in a HorizontalScrollView doesn't work as intended

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` with a `RelativeLayout` containing three `View`s. One is centered in parent, and the other two should be placed relative the centered view as anchor. This doesn't give the intended results. But when the `RelativeLayout` is *not* placed inside the scroll view, it does.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#eeeeee">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/center"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#ff0000" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
            android:background="#00ff00" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
            android:background="#0000ff" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The code above gives the following result:

[image: HorizontalScrollView]

The space on the left side has the same width as the red (centered) view, as of it was placed to the right if it *before* it was centered. The green view is placed outside (to the left) the container with the same reasoning. Why aren't the layout of the green and blue views updated correctly when the red view is centered?

However, if I just use the `RelativeLayout` without placing it in the scroll view it works as intended.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#eeeeee">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#ff0000" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
        android:background="#00ff00" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
        android:background="#0000ff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: RelativeLayout]

This side-by-side alignment is just to give a simple showcase. In practice, margins (both positive and negative) will be added to make a gap or overlap between the views, hence a `LinearLayout` would not do the trick.

The note at the [Android documentation for RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) suggests that there is a known issue regarding this. Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you change RelativeLayout with LinearLayout, what is happening?

Comment: LinearLayout gives the expected behavior, but that doesn't allow me to change the z-index so that the green and blue views can have negative margins and overlap the red view. Bringing green to front places it last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RelativeLayout` needs to be wrapped within a `LinearLayout` for the layout calculations to be forced to position the views in the right order.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#eeeeee">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/center"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#ff0000" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/left"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
                android:background="#00ff00" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/right"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
                android:background="#0000ff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

as a reader not poster I cannot comment yet, so just a tip as an answer here...

**This might help**
did you try to add (in ):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

or
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

depends on approach...

most examples are unfortunately using LinearLayout

Have a read at:
[HorizontalScrollView API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)
:)